# MYSQL counting presence of value (is not null)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
id  | module_id | answered 
 1       4           3
 2       4           1
 3       4          NULL
 4       5          NULL 
 5       5           1
```

I need to calculate the number of the rows for each module_id and the number of rows where answered isn't NULL.

so I need the result

```
module_id  | row_count  |  answered
    4            3            2
    5            2            1
```

So far I have

```
SELECT module_id, COUNT(*) as row_count FROM table GROUP BY module_id
```

but I have no idea how to do the answered column. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 COUNT(answered)
```

will count the non-null values in that particular column.

That's why COUNT(*) is a lot faster than COUNT(some-column).

Answer (score 0):

if you use COUNT(column) it will only count non-null value rows.

Count function has three variants:

- COUNT(*) counts all rows
- COUNT(column) counts non-NULLs only
- COUNT(1) is the same as COUNT(*) because 1 is a non-null expressions

Your use of COUNT(*) or COUNT(column) should be based on the desired output only.